# createRecord with belongsTo association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to store a record with a belongsTo association, but the associated ID is always empty:

**Customer Model**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  projects:    DS.hasMany('project',{ async: true })
});
```

**Project Model**

```
Docket.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  customer:    DS.belongsTo('customer')
});
```

**Save action in ProjectsController**

```
var _this = this;

// create new record
var project = this.store.createRecord('project', this.getProperties('name','number', 'description', 'archived'));

// add customer with id 22 to project
this.store.find('customer', 22).then(function(customer) {
  project.set('customer', customer);
});

// save if validation passes, otherwise show errors
project.save().then(function(){
  _this.resetAndCloseForm(form);
}, function(response){
  _this.set('errors',response.errors);
});
```

The json sended to server is always this:

```
archived: false
customer_id: null
description: null
name: "foobar"
number: null
```

I want to choose the customer of the project in a selectbox. Are there any smart ways to get the selected customer as record or do I have to load it over the ID?

```
{{view Ember.Select
    viewName="select"
    contentBinding="customers"
    optionLabelPath="content.name"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    prompt="Pick a customer:"
    selectionBinding="selectedCustomer"
}}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, can you tell me how fixed the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an old version of ember data, or do you have a custom serializer, cause it should be sending it up without the `_id`.  Try upgrading or show your serializer.

And you are saving before the find is resolved.

```
// add customer with id 22 to project
this.store.find('customer', 22).then(function(customer) {
  project.set('customer', customer);


  // save if validation passes, otherwise show errors
  project.save().then(function(){
    _this.resetAndCloseForm(form);
  }, function(response){
    _this.set('errors',response.errors);
  });

});
```

and it looks like `selectedCustomer` has the record.

```
// create new record
var project = this.store.createRecord('project', this.getProperties('name','number', 'description', 'archived'));

 project.set('customer', this.get('selectedCustomer'));

// save if validation passes, otherwise show errors
project.save().then(function(){
  _this.resetAndCloseForm(form);
}, function(response){
  _this.set('errors',response.errors);
});
```

you can also set the `optionValuePath='content'`

Comment: Yep, I'm now saving the record after find is resolved, but I wonder if there is an easier way to do that. Is there any way to get the customer record directly from the selectbox? I'm using Ember Data 1.0.0 Beta 4. And I'm using this `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({});` Furthermore, I want that Ember sends `customer_id` to my API.

Comment: How can I prefill this selectbox on an editing modal/overlay form? It works with all other fields, but the selectbox isn't populated: `var project = this.store.find('project', id).then(function(data) { _this.set('selectedCustomer',data.get('customer')); });`

Comment: Or please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503810/find-record-from-belongsto-association-in-ember-js