# Find record from belongsTo association in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I get the associated record from an Ember model? Or: how to get the record from the Promise Object?

**Customer model**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  projects:    DS.hasMany('project',{ async: true })
});
```

**Project model**

```
Docket.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  customer:    DS.belongsTo('customer', { async: true })
});
```

**Find method**

```
var project = this.store.find('project', id).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.get('customer').toString());
});
```

**Console output**

```
<DS.PromiseObject:ember654>
```

**JSON response**

```
{"projects":[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"test",
    "number":"a310",
    "description":null,
    "archived":false,
    "customer_id":22
  }
]};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use another then on the get :)

```
var project = this.store.find('project', id).then(function(data) {
  data.get('customer').then(function(c){
    console.log(c);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh damn! Facepalm. Thanks!