# Ember "Params is not defined" in routing

Tags: javascript, function, ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember and am building a very simple app. I can navigate from my breeders index page(/breeders) to my breeders show page(/breeders/:breeder_id) by clicking on the link generated by the link-to tag. However if I manually navigate to breeders/1 or any of other breeders.show routes I get the following error:

```
Error while loading route: ReferenceError: params is not defined
at Catapp.BreedersShowRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model
```

I can't figure out what I've done that is causing this.

This is what I think is the relevant code:

```
    //router.js
    Catapp.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('breeders', function() {
            this.route('new');
            this.route('show', {path: '/:breeder_id'});
        });
    });

    Catapp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        redirect: function(){
            this.transitionTo('breeders.index');
        }
    });

    Catapp.BreedersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(){
            return this.store.find('breeder');
        }
    });

    Catapp.BreedersShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(){
            return this.store.find('breeder', params.breeder_id);
        }
    });
```

.

```
// breeders_controller.js
Catapp.BreedersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['id']
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to actually add the argument to the model hook

```
Catapp.BreedersShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('breeder', params.breeder_id);
    }
});
```

You can call it whatever you like as well

```
Catapp.BreedersShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(foo){
        return this.store.find('breeder', foo.breeder_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: For those that came here and realised this doesn't work for them, it's most likely because you aren't in the `index` route for that model: the only place `params` works. I used [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20503866/1450226) instead.

Comment: I'd love to add additional info to the answer, but I'm not sure if I understand what you're referring to.  The params are populated based on where the `:foo` is in the router.

Comment: If you are on the URL `/:foo` params contains data. But as soon as you are nested anywhere, such as `/:foo/edit` params doesn't contain anything. I needed to access the `:foo` ID from a nested route.