# Ember Data Store Find returns empty content on second call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have a model with a Fixtures data set, so no backend involved in here. For the model, I have 22 data records. When I query it for the first time in my IndexRoute, all 22 data records are returned. No problem here.

When I leave the route, and come back later, the model hook of my IndexRoute is called again, but this time the same query does not return data.

My Model hook looks like:

```
model: function () {
    var placeId = 0;

    console.log('Index Route: Model Hook');
    console.log('Getting hints for place ' + placeId);

    this.get('store').find('hint', { place: placeId })
        .then(
            function (hints) {
                console.log('Found hints', hints.get('content'));
            }
        );

    return this.get('store').find('hint', { place: placeId });
}
```

As you can see, for demo purposes I always query hints with place id equal to zero. As already said, the first time it returns the data (and I can see the data in the Chrome Ember Inspector), but the second time I enter this route does not return the data (which I know is out there).

Edit:
My hint model looks basically like

```
App.Hint = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    // some basic boring attributes
    place: DS.belongsTo('place', { async: true }) // Association with my Place Model
});

App.Place = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    // some more attributes
    hints: DS.hasMany('hint', { async: true })
});
```

So the query `{place: placeId}` simply gets all those hints who have an association with a specific place. The problem is not that the query does not work - it works the first time the Index Route is triggered (and it works as I expect it to work). The problem is that all subsequent calls of index route, and all other locations that are trying to access hints, do not work anymore and always return an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer. The problem seems to be related to finding the hint records through the belongsTo association with my places.

Anyway, I found this post [Find record from belongsTo association in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503810/find-record-from-belongsto-association-in-ember-js) and this is how the actual solution looks like:

```
model: function () {
    var placeId = 0;

    return this.store.find('place', placeId)
        .then(function (place) {
            return place.get('hints');
        })
        .then(function (hints) {
            return hints;
        });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about what `{ place: placeId }` is supposed to be doing, since i am not sure if fixtureAdapter can mimic server queries (never tried).

That said however, if you want your route to always return all the 'hints' in your fixture data, all you should need to do is this:

```
return this.store.find('hint');
```

note: you only need to call once.

if that still does not work. try posting what your fixture data and adapter looks like.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear about my models, their association and what I'm trying to achieve.